# get multiple image from phone?

Tags: android, xml

i'm trying to select multiple image from my phone memory using Intent and store uri in array but i have no idea how can i do this please help me.

i'm able to get only one image uri this is my code:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                Uri uri=data.getData();
    }
```

using "intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);" it give me permission for selecting multiple image but after selection how can i get uri all selected image ??

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uri is not obtained always in the same way, normally I use this method to extrapolate one value:

```
private Uri detectFileToUploadUri(Intent data) {
    Uri result = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip = data.getClipData();
        if (clip != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clip.getItemCount(); i++) {
                Uri uri = clip.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                if (uri != null) {
                    result = uri;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (result == null && data.getData() != null) {
        result = data.getData();
    }
    return result;
}
```

To get more Uri, you can remove the break and add the result to the uri list.

```
        ClipData clip = data.getClipData();
        if (clip != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clip.getItemCount(); i++) {
                Uri uri = clip.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                if (uri != null) {
                    results.add(uri);
                }
            }
        }
```

Also it would be better to insert an if in your onActivityResult code: "if (requestCode == 1)".